# Netsuite Suite Script 2.0 getSelectOptions function on record field does not exist

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to get the values from the `Status` select field on a customer record so that I can get the proper `internal id`. I should note that I am trying to create a new customer and I am at the point where I need to set the entitystatus.

According to the documentation for Suite Script 2.0 there is a method called getSelectOptions() on the Field object of a record. For some reason when I try to call that method I get an error saying that it does not exist.

Below is my code for my restlet:

```
define([ 'N/record', 'N/search' ],
function(record, search) {
    function doPost(requestBody) {
        var custRec = record.create({
            type : record.Type.CUSTOMER
        });

        var statusRec = custRec.getField({
            fieldId : 'entitystatus'
        });

        var status = statusRec.getSelectOptions({
            filter : 'CUSTOMER-Closed Won',
            operator : 'is'
        });

        return JSON.stringify(status);
    }
}
```

If I return statusRec as a JSON string I get back `{"id":"entitystatus","label":"Status","type":"select"}`

But when I call `statusRec.getSelectOptions(options)` it returns error code: `JS_EXCEPTION error message:TypeError: Cannot find function getSelectOptions in object Field.`

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Maybe there is a better way to do what I want without hard coding the internal ids.

Comment: entitystatus is one of a number of built-in fields where field looks like a list/record type but really it's not. Since entitystatus is not likely to be a highly dynamic field you could easily just hard-code the status value or use a script parameter to select the target value to be used.

Comment: @bknights Is it the same for subsidiary, because it is giving me the same error? We have several custom entries in subsidiary. I just want to make sure that once it comes out of the sandbox that things don't break because of hard coded internal ids

Comment: @bknights I have the script parameter set but for some reason I can only find documentation on how to reference one in suite script 1.0. I have tried `custRec.getField({fieldId: 'custscript_default_entity_status'})` but that returns null.

Comment: I don't know about Subsidiary. It should be a regular field -- it's mostly the older state/status fields that are irregular. However again I'd go with a script parameter. For some fields you can also try the set Text method -- I don't know what the SS2.0 equivalent is but for subsidiary you might try record.setFieldText('subsidiary', 'SubsidiaryName/ID"); This of course is fragile if someone changes the subsidiary name so if the subsidiary is a fixed value a script parameter is the way to go.

Comment: @bknights I agree with the script parameter idea in case we decide to change something some day we don't have to change the code. I am new to NetSuite and still trying to figure everything out so thanks for the help.

Comment: Got it!   `var curScript = runtime.getCurrentScript();
  var defEntity = curScript.getParameter({
   name : 'custscript_default_entity_status'
  });`